About correct action after updating the closed question?
I have asked the below question, which is closed:
About Freud psychology system tracking in Middle East socials [closed]
So I have tried to answer the opinion base and closing comments as you can see below:

The "level 4 defense mechanisms" are not Freudian. They come from
theories developed by George Vaillant –  Chris Rogers  21 hours ago 1


On top of that, looking at the rest of the question, it is based
purely on opinions and suppositions without any real psychological
basis. For example, "due to the weak foundations of other mechanisms
in mature level (4), such as altruism, it will create narcissism and
dictatorships personality on this area" can you provide some concrete
evidence to back your claims? How does altruism lead to narcissism and
dictatorships? That being said, I think any answers will purely be
based on opinion anyway. –  Chris Rogers  20 hours ago


I googled your
word about the altruism lead to narcissism, and in this paper said
:The results suggest that there is a relationship between certain traits within the narcissism spectrum and the proclivity to engage in extreme altruism also in abstract show some signs of about needs to
have the power of other mechanisms in mature level (4) like prediction to achive the alturism from the narcissism

but it has been closed, So I have added some update on it as you can see:
Update 1:
As the question recognized to be opinion base and closed, I add this request about some comment or answer for introducing proper tags for finding the academic papers on social science and psychology science field about the connection of psychological defense system and cultural defense system?
Update 2:
I have removed some part of this question about
reading this post and add below details:

I guess I must write a comment on the question by using the
@username of those closed the question. But is asked here about if i
remove the @username then it doesn't notify those closed the question,
am i right?


The meta post you linked to appears to answer your questions.

Excuse me @Arnon_Weinberg, I have read it better and so update the question.

As I pointed out in the comments to your question, when providing prior research information it should be added to the question and not provided in comments as not everyone reads the comments for one thing. So, I edited the information into your question to help.
If you want to address a particular person with your comment, using @username alerts the person in there message inbox that there is a comment for them. However, you don't need to use @username under their question or answer as they will be notified of all comments.
If you or anyone else feels the edits are enough to address the issue(s) which closed the question, votes can be made by you or will be given by others for reopening your question using the link under your question.
